How to turn off print log in Android when using TensorFlow Lite?
Too many repeat logs ...
It is log img
I can not find anywhere turn off tflite logs. Although Log does not affect the operation, but too many repeated logs I feel unnecessary, is there a way to turn off log output?

I don't think you can delete them. You have to build the library yourself without the comments. Prolly you need to report it to github issues.
